# Exception of "Could not load file or assembly System.Buffers" while using ConfigurationBuilder

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm trying to build a configuration file using `ConfigurationBuilder` but keep getting an exception of:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Below is where the exception is occurring:

```
ConfigurationWrapper config = new ConfigurationWrapper(new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build());
```

Stack Trace:

> at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
>      at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(String json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.ParseStream(Stream input)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
>      at Project.AzureFunctions.ProcessNotificationQueue.d__6.MoveNext()

I'm at a loss of what to do and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems you are using a abstract class `ConfigurationWrapper`? Can you show more details? Such as the assembly you are using or more information of your function, otherwise it will be hard to reproduce your exception.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it can not find the file. The program will most likely be trying to open the appsettings.json file in the projects Bin/Debug folder (Assuming your projects build configuration is set to debug and not release). It may not be automatically copied there. It could also depend upon if you have other projects and which one is the default.

A quick way to test this would be to give it the full path to the appsettings.json file.
ie: .AddJsonFile(@"c:\settings\appsettings.json"   if your json file is located in c:\settings.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. That was an issue at one point but I'm pretty sure the file is there. If I do `Directory.GetFiles(context.FunctionAppDirectory)` I can see the `appsettings.json` file. :/

Comment: If you are positive the file is there, you might then verify it is a valid json file.  I use a free site that parses json online.  https://jsoneditoronline.org/, if you do much work with Json you will love this site (I have no affiliation with  the site, just a happy user).